# Reading & modifying data from lib file using perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have to read & modify certain data from .lib file.
I could extract the line in which the data is present, but I could not extract the number associated with it.

```
open my $fh, "<" ,".....lib" or die "$!";

while(my $line = <$fh>) {
      if ($line =~ m/xyz0/) {
         print $line;
      }
}
```

The code outputs the line:

```
+xyz0 = 0.005 hg = 0.9 rvfd = 75
```

I want to extract the value beside xyz0 from it. How do I do it ?

Answer (score 4):

```
if ($line =~ m/xyz0 = (\S+)/){
    print $1;
}
```

Comment: Or if you want to avoid global vars: `if ( my ($xyz0) = $line =~ m/xyz0 = (\S+)/) { print $xyz0, "\n"; }`

Comment: @rahdirs And if you are uncertain about spaces around `=` make it `/xyz0\s*=\s*(\S+)/`

Comment: How can I change the extracted value to some new number ? like 0.9 ?

Comment: @rahdirs one way would be with the [substitution operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators)

Comment: @zdim,@ysth,@ikegami:                                                                               `while(my $line = <$fh>){                                                                                        if( my ($xyz0) = $line =~m/xyz0 = (\S+)/){                                                              print $xyz0,"\n"; # this prints 0.005                                                        $new_value = 0.9;                                                                                    $xyz0 =~ s/$xyz0/$new_value/; # How do I enter this value to file ?}}`.

Comment: @rahdirs In principle you need to rewrite the whole file.  Search SO for that, there already are many posts.

Comment: @zdim,@ysth,@ikegami: Why do I have to rewrite the whole file ? I only need to increment the value by 15% each time

Comment: that's just how files work.  unless you are updating a specific number of bytes in the file, if you want to change something you need to rewrite the whole remainder of the file.

Comment: in any case, this is a very separate question, so ask it as one